# Auto-expand the editor size up to the screen/view size while the text grows

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, editor, markdown-preview

For
example,
if
I
am
typing
and
I
hit
the
editor
current
box
size,
instead
of
adding
the
scroll
bar,
expand
the
editor
box
size
up
to
the
screen
view
size.
Only
then,
add
the
scroll
bar.

This is something which always bothered. But recently, GitHub added this feature:
[image]

---

#### Actual Behavior

[image]

---

#### Expected Behavior

[image]

#### Other

This same behavior should apply when editing a question (On GitHub also does this). On this case, if the question is small enough it already fits on the text editor view area without a scroll bar, do nothing. But if the questions body is bigger than the standard text editor size, expand it up to the maximum view size, only then add a scroll bar.

#### Conflicting

As someone will probably complain, the GitHub and StackExchange websites text editor have a main difference, GitHub has a `Preview` button, while StackExchange directly shows the `Preview` just bellow the text editor, related to an WYSIWYG text editor.

On this case, when I say `expand the editor up to the view size`, it should also consider the space taken by `WYSIWYG Preview` area, and not literally expand to the full extend of the view area.

Now a problem rises when the editor text is very big and the preview area is also very big. How it should expand? For me, the text editor can expand up to `75%` of the view size, while the other remaining `25%` stays reserved for the preview area.

I would say it is already good size as default. If someone likes it to be bigger than `75%`, should be simple enough for them to increase. If someone likes it smaller more like `50% - 50%`, is also should be simple enough for them to decrease it.

I just cannot think anyone can adequately work with the text editor size with the size of `25%` of the screen as it currently is, when the question text is bigger. Because you can barely see where you are on the text, and what are the other things you have. And as the preview area is fixed to only show you the top of the question, it does not make much sense to have a preview area showing up on `75%` of the screen, while you are probably working on something out at the middle/end of the question text with a text editor with `25%` of view size.

Comment: Current workaround: resize the editor manually (the grip on the bottom can be dragged to resize), or use 3rd-party markdown editor like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)

Comment: @andmyself _Current workaround: resize the editor manually_ - this isn't a workaround :-| this is a normal feature I think OP knows this. StackEdit is an interesting tool, I had hoped it would integrate with the site but it's a separate tool :(